# Join and explode nested list and dictionary in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm struggling to normalize a dataframe with columns containing nested list and dictionary. I've tried combinations of zip, json_normlize and explode without success.

Here's code to create example of current layout with nesting:

```
d = {
    'user_id': 'user1',
    'user_emails': [['user1@workemail.example', 'user1@home_email.example']],
    'user_emails_data': [[{'type': 'emailAddress', 'id': 1}, {'type': 'emailAddress', 'id': 2}]] }
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
```

[image: Current Output]

[[image: Desired output]

Comment: is your definition of `d` right? I think you should have single `[]` not double and the first value should be `["user1", "user1"]` maybe?

Comment: @Dan I thought so too, but if we create a surrogate index then it doesn't matter assuming the objects are of the same length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in two steps, we can use `.explode` and `pd.json_normalize` and `.join` to re-create your df.

```
uid = df.set_index('user_id')['user_emails'].explode().reset_index()

df1 = uid.join(pd.json_normalize(df['user_emails_data'].explode()))

print(df1)

  user_id               user_emails          type  id
0   user1   user1@workemail.example  emailAddress   1
1   user1  user1@home_email.example  emailAddress   2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I will go about it:

```
d['user_emails'] = d['user_emails'][0]

d["user_emails_data"] = d["user_emails_data"][0]

d["user_emails_data_type"] = []
d["user_emails_data_id"] = []

for val in d["user_emails_data"]:
    d["user_emails_data_type"].append(val["type"])
    d["user_emails_data_id"].append(val['id'])

del d["user_emails_data"]


pd.DataFrame(d)
```

This generates:

```
    user_id user_emails           user_emails_data_type user_emails_data_id
0   user1   user1@workemail.example     emailAddress    1
1   user1   user1@home_email.example    emailAddress    2
```

It assumes that rest of the `dict` has the same structure.